# Good book about Akka library and actor-based concurrency model

Tags: actor, akka

I am looking for a book which cover [Akka](http://akka.io/) in detail.  Specifically the book should cover best practices in actor-based concurrency, what pitfalls should be aware of?  I actually tried  searching for a while but could not find even a book about Akka.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Already plowed through the 330 pages of [Akka Documentation](http://doc.akka.io/)?

Comment: Not quite yet.  I am doing that now and was wondering if there is any other source of information.

Comment: I'd have a look at: http://www.artima.com/shop/actors_in_scala
Then you can read some Erlang books to get a firmer grip on message passing concurrency.

Comment: Will read it.  Thanks Viktor.

Comment: 638 pages (java & scala) free: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/Akka.pdf
I think this should be the first book anyway (after "Alice in wonderland" of course). But I should say it is not hard to understand how it work, but harder: where it to apply. Samples and use-cases are important.

Comment: Almost double the number of pages in just a year :) We're constantly working to improve the documentation, and Patterns and blogposts on letitcrash.com is equally important.

Comment: The Akka documentation is great, but a book format sometimes helps with getting started and getting a great overview. Books have less details and more working examples. It helps prepare the mind for the documentation.

Answer (score 4):

How about [Akka in Action](http://www.manning.com/roestenburg/)? Once it is out of MEAP of course.